# Play then pause multiple visible videos on webpage one after the other - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html5-video

I have multiple videos ( 3 per row and 3 rows) on a webpage that is essentially going to act as a video wall. Currently all the videos are playing simultaneously on an endless loop which is really making the media player struggle.

What I would like to do it have each video play 1 after the other. Is there some Javascript I could use to achieve this? I would probably need to give each Video Tag/element an Id?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please upload some sample code!